# Create tiles given images and locations; convert markers to tiles

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, web-mapping, tiles, markers

**What I need**

I need to convert a list of markers to a tile layer

I've been googleing without success how to do this. Anyone has faced this problem and has a nice easy solution?

**Why I need it**

I've developed a HTML application that displays a map. This map has many fixed markers (they do not change in time). Due to that:

1. I want to speed up the application
2. I want to hide the marker position from malicious users (so they can't use the information I've gathered for they're own porpose)

I want to convert the markers to a tile layer.

Thanks!

Comment: Your "Question" looks like it is asking three questions: 1. How to speed up the application? 2. How to hide the marker position from malicious users 3. How to convert the markers to a tile layer?  My recommendation would be that three Questions be posted.

Comment: @PolyGeo My question is How to convert the markers to a tile layer, I've posted the other things to contextualize.

Comment: That changes my recommendation to using that as the title of your question and editing the body of it to make that more obvious.

Comment: @PolyGeo changed

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to reinvent the wheel. Among [the solutions for too many markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers?hl=sv), there is one called [Fusion Table Layers](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers?hl=sv#fusiontables). They act as a layer, which is rendered at Google servers - so it is very fast.

You can find live examples in the [Google Developer's Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-simple).

Comment: If he wants to use the Google Fusion Tables layer, the table he uses will have to be shared. That means that I (as a malicious user) can simply look at his code, grab the table id from it, go to the fusion table and download the whole stuff in like 5 minutes.